# Inserting text within a block automaticaly for each Enter button pressing?

Tags: vimrc, key-bindings

I write LaTeX code in vim. I also installed vim-latex. When I am inside a `itemize` block that means inside `\begin{itemize}....\end{itemize}` I enter <kbd>Enter</kbd> and add new `\item ....`.

If vim can detect the block and add `\item` command when I enter <kbd>Enter</kbd> inside that block it easy very helpful to and I can make same things for another block also.

I guess it may be possible in vim.

I am waiting vim's super expert(super hero).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be achieved very simply using the following pattern, using a conditional expression map and `searchpairpos` which detects the presence of an unclosed itemize environment:

```
function! CheckItemize()
    let [l:lnum, l:cnum] = searchpairpos('\\begin{itemize}', '',
                \  '\\end{itemize}', 'nbW')
    return l:lnum > 0
endfunction

inoremap <expr> <cr> CheckItemize() ? '<cr><tab>\item ' : '<cr>'
```

Depending on your indent settings, you may use instead:

```
inoremap <expr> <cr> CheckItemize() ? '<cr>\item ' : '<cr>'
```

Comment: works, but `\item` shift left one tab each time. see this https://pasteboard.co/H90pzhR.png

Comment: Although your solution works, but I don't understand all terms you use. If you give your code's explanation or link it is better for understanding others as well as I.

Comment: How can I modify your answer so that it also works for command `o`?